# Unable to rm without confirmation on linux

Tags: linux

So, I have a folder called Bar in directory Foo, which is a soft symlink to another folder located elsewhere.

I am in directory Foo. Now I want to delete the build folder recursively.

If I do rm -rf Bar, then the symlink is removed, but the actual contents are not removed. If I do rm -rf Bar/* then the contents of Bar are removed from the original location (which is what I want) but it does not listen to the -f option. It always confirms before removing. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I just tested that and, for me using GNU `rm`, `rm` _did_ obey `-f`.  Please provide more details.  What is the output of `type rm` and `rm --version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Understand the problem:

```
$ rm() { /bin/rm --interactive=always "$@"; }
$ mkdir -p rmtest && touch rmtest/a rmtest/b rmtest/c rmtest/d && rm -rf rmtest
$ rm() { /bin/rm "$@" --interactive=always; }
$ mkdir -p rmtest && touch rmtest/a rmtest/b rmtest/c rmtest/d && rm -rf rmtest
/bin/rm: descend into directory 'rmtest'? y
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file 'rmtest/b'? y
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file 'rmtest/a'? y
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file 'rmtest/d'? y
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file 'rmtest/c'? y
/bin/rm: remove directory 'rmtest'? y
```

This `--interactive=always` (or `-I` or `-i`) thing can be done at least using

a) a function
b) an ordinary wrapper script

BTW: It can not be done using an alias, because there the `--interactive`  argument would be first.

You'll have to check each of this to get rid of this behavior, or you can explicitly call e.g. `/bin/rm` or `/usr/bin/rm`

Check if there is a shell function rm

```
set | grep "^rm ()"
```

get rid of it with

```
unset rm
```

Or modify it to have the interactive argument first so it can be overridden

```
rm() { /bin/rm --interactive=always "$@"; }
```

Find a shell script:

```
which rm
```

or

```
type -p rm
```

then

```
file $whatever_path_was_shown
```

e.g.

```
file /bin/rm
```

if it is a shell script

```
$EDITOR /bin/rm
```

and move the `--interactive` argument to the front

If you don't have root access, hide the shell script using a function or alias pointing back to original rm